# Can't uploading on Atmega328P-MU after a while

Tags: arduino, atmega

I am having a problem to upload sketches via Arduino IDE on the Atmega328P-MU chip on a custom board.

Shortly after I have mounted the chip on the board everything works fine. I can upload a bootloader and then sketches. After a certain time, suddenly everything seems to freeze(LED-blinking, etc.). I found out that if I heat up the chip again, everything works fine for another little while again (2-5min). This procedure is relatively reproducible for me.
I have tried it with many chips from two different suppliers.
Note that I can just "reset" the chip to a working state, if I heat it up and upload a new bootloader.

My guess is that I might not even heat up the chip only, but instead another component and therefore changing its values to work properly. Is that a possibility? What values of the other components might cause that behaviour? Though, when trying to heat up just other parts nothing will work.

Schematics for chip can be found right [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dMfx.jpg).

Comment: There is nothing in the MCU schematics that would explain this behaviour. If it is a hardware problem, it is in a part of a schematic you don't show, like on the power supply or reset or other devices.

Comment: Problem also appears when just assembling the MCU schematic. So it is a layout problem? Distance of the Resistors of the Crystal is max. 7mm and to the MCU 8mm. Bypass caps are max. 8.5 mm away. That shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: I can't comment because you tell no info on the layout. Or what provides power supply. Or what measurements you have performed. Not even the AVR Fuse Bits which are very important for selecting proper oscillation mode for the crystal. Does the crystal oscillate? Is there a pull-up on RESET pin? But the problem should not be in the parts you have shown or told.

Comment: @Justme Thanks for your input, I have updated the schematics. For tests it receives its power via USB. AVR Fuses are set to standard values, bootloader is for the Arduino Uno. If more information is need, please let me know.

Comment: There is no pull up resistor on reset pin could be the first reason as internal pull up is weak. USB supply could have ripple and noise and be less that what is required for 16MHz operation. So you are powering a fan and a speaker from an IO pin? And the SD card interface most likely does not work, depending on the relative voltages of MCU supply, card supply, and SPI clock speed.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Pullup resistor of the reset is on the second page at the CP2012N. Fan/speaker isn't connected(would be just a little buzzer). SD-Card inteface works like a charm actually, because I use the 3.3V from the internal LDO from the CP2102N.  I am quite unsure what could cause the described behaviour. You got any other ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same behaviour with external less noise 5V supply.

Comment: When using the Internal crystal everything works fine. Might be actually, that the fuses are wrongly set. I thought by uploading the bootloader for the arduino uno (it has a 16mhz crystal) I would already set the fuses properly. That assumption was wrong right?

Comment: I don't know how you uploaded the bootloader, so I don't know if the program you used to upload it also programs the fuse bits for you or not. Just beware that be absolutely sure how they are supposed to be set. Programming them incorrectly can permanently cause the chip to not work.